# How do I extend my desktop to my 2nd monitor rather than just cloning it?

Tags: debian, drivers, display

I have just installed Debian Wheezy for the first time and have had mixed success getting my system up and running. Currently my main issue is that I am unable to extend my desktop to my second screen.

I have an ATI radeon HD 7700 series graphics card connected to 2 displays. Running `lspci` results in this line, among others:

> 04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cape Verde [Radeon HD 7700 Series]

Currently, both are cloned. I initially tried to follow the [instructions for installing proprietary ATI drivers](https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary), which resulted in the 2nd display being detected but I was unable to extend the desktop rather than clone it (something about my virtual screen not being big enough).

I gathered that support might be better for the free version so I followed these [instructions for removing said drivers](http://linuxg.net/how-to-properly-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers-on-debian-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/), followed by [these instructions to install the free ones](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo).

As per the troubleshooting step in that page I ran this command:

> dmesg | grep -E 'drm|radeon' | grep -iE 'firmware|microcode'

which produced this output:

```
[    4.925773] [drm] Loading VERDE Microcode  
[    4.990158] platform radeon_cp.0: firmware: agent loaded radeon/VERDE_pfp.bin into memory 
[    5.152647] platform radeon_cp.0: firmware: agent loaded radeon/VERDE_me.bin into memory 
[    5.236165] platform radeon_cp.0: firmware: agent loaded radeon/VERDE_ce.bin into memory [    5.260082] platform radeon_cp.0: firmware: agent loaded radeon/VERDE_rlc.bin into memory 
[    5.376566] platform radeon_cp.0: firmware: agent loaded radeon/VERDE_mc.bin into memory
```

That's different to the outputs on that page but then they don't really give anymore information so I just assumed everything had worked.

Anywho, now when I go to `System Tools` -> `Preferences` -> `System Settings` -> `Display` I just see a single display called `Unknown`, which clones across both of my monitors.

running `xrandr -q` produces this output:

> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0:
>   minimum 1680 x 1050, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 1680 x 1050 default
>   connected 1680x1050+0+0 0mm x 0mm    1680x1050       0.0*

FYI 1680x1050 is the native resolution of both monitors. I do not have a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file, and my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` directory seems to be empty.

This is my first time running a linux system so I'm totally confused and would appreciate kind words and idiot-proof guidance.

Comment: Could you include the full output of `xrandr -q` with the screen connected please?

Comment: @terdo that is the full output.

Comment: Try the A from this AU Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/71457/how-can-i-set-up-dual-monitor-display-with-ati-driver

Comment: @slm I reinstalled the proprietary drivers (https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary) and restarted. Running `gksudo amdcccle` as per that answer produces this output: `(gksudo:4955): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running` and nothing opens..

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz - seems like DBUS isn't running but that doesn't make any sense to me. I've posted this to 2 of our resident Debian/Ubuntu/Mint guys to see if they have any thoughts in the chatroom: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15044646#15044646

Comment: @slm adding the line `virtual 3360 1050` to the `Display` subsection of `xorg.conf` fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Try using `sudo amdcccle` instead. Also, please [edit] your question and show the current output of `xrandr`.

Comment: Also if DBUS isn't running try this: `service dbus start`

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz - I'll copy the gist of that A to this Q, you can then accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this answer on AU in a Q&A titled: [How can I set up dual monitor display with ATI driver?](https://askubuntu.com/a/103310/17531).

*excerpt*

> 1. Open a terminal and type:
>
>    ```
>      $ gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
>    ```
> 2. In the sub-section "display" add this code or modify if already exist:
>
>    ```
>      virtual 2880 1024
>    ```
> 3. Where 2880 and 1024 are the value returned by the error: required
>      virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(2880, 1024),
>      minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(1600, 1600).
> 4. Restart the computer.
> 5. Then you will be able to extend your desktop without issue.

In the OP's configuration he opted to use this:

```
virtual 3360 1050
```